# Solving congruences using PARI

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key, prime-numbers

I'm having trouble finding info in the docs about how to solve a system of congruences. The closest I can find is 'matsolvemod' in here: http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/dochtml/html.stable/Vectors,_matrices,_linear_algebra_and_sets.html

but I'm not sure if that's exactly what it's used for because I don't really understand where the M parameter comes in with a system of congruences. Is there a function for solving a system of linear equations of the form:

x = a1 (mod b1)
x = a2 (mod b2)
...
x = an (mod bn)

(or even for just 2 or 3 congruences is fine)

EDIT: Okay, I've tried just using the algorithm and basic arithmetic instead of finding a function to do it for me automatically but am receiving an error:

[image]

Comment: Did you read the algorithm outlined on the Wikipedia page I linked in your previous question? There's a walkthrough with 2 congruences (pairwise coprime, though) and then for the general case. Then you can implement it using only standard arithmetic and a modular inverse algorithm (which PARI should have). If this is about using a built-in function of PARI/GP to solve general systems of congruences, it's off-topic here.

Comment: I've edited the comment to show how I've attempted to solve the example system of congruence you gave in my last question

Comment: I don't know much about PARI/GP but I think `Mod` does more than just take the value of `a` modulo `b` (it changes its datatype, too). Can you try just using `a%b` instead? Though I'm not sure how to get the modular inverse in that case, you'll need to look that up. I'm sorry, I'm not of much help - I don't use PARI/GP.

Comment: That works- thanks! Both of your answers have been really helpful to me even though you don't use PARI/GP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pari's "chinese" function (as in Chinese Remainder Theorem) does the solution for you, for two congruences. You can fold in more congruences via induction.

```
? chinese(Mod(42,91), Mod(11, 37))
%1 = Mod(3045, 3367)
```

The previous example solves for $x \equiv 42 \pmod{91}$ and $x \equiv 11 \pmod{37}$, which is unique modulo $91 \cdot 37 = 3367$. You can use "raise" to promote a Mod object to the integers.

Comment: Actually .. it is `lift` and not `raise`